# R with replacement in dataframe, error "non-existent rows not allowed"

Tags: r, replace

I have an odd problem when doing replacement in my dataframe. I want to keep the topN values in every column, and replace others with zero, here is my function:

```
remain_topN_word <- function(df, n) {
  for(col in colnames(df)) {
    topV <- sort(df[,col],decreasing = T)[n]
    if(topV > 0) {
      df[df[, grep(col, colnames(df))] < topV, col] <- 0
    }
    print(col)
  }
  return(df)
}
```

my data is something like this:

```
c <- data.frame(replicate(10,rnorm(9000)))
```

then i use my function, and get the error

```
 d <- remain_topN_word(c[,1:10], 3)
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df[, grep(col, colnames(df))] < topV,  : 
  non-existent rows not allowed
Called from: `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df[, grep(col, colnames(df))] < topV, 
    col, value = 0)
```

if i only use the function with my first 9 columns or my last 2 columns, everything will be ok.

```
d <- remain_topN_word(c[,1:9], 3)
[1] "X1"
[1] "X2"
[1] "X3"
[1] "X4"
[1] "X5"
[1] "X6"
[1] "X7"
[1] "X8"
[1] "X9"

d <- remain_topN_word(c[,9:10], 3)
[1] "X9"
[1] "X10"
```

here is my sessionInfo:
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

i would appreciate it if u can figure this out, thank you in advance.

Comment: You are selecting two columns with df[, grep(col, colnames(df))]. grep matches the first and last col names. Try replacing that with df[, col] and you should be all set.

Comment: you are right, thank you so much!